# Title Field Display Name Reads User's ID

Tags: 2013, list, document-library

For some reason, the Title field in all Lists and Libraries reads as 'User's ID' instead of Title.  I did not make any changes to the Title column; I do have custom css but literally the only thing that is changed is the .ms-full-width style background, and the colors.

I'm assuming the cause of this is someone renamed the Display Name for a Title field and it applied it across the site level.

Is there any way CSS can override the display name of a column??

Answer (score 1):

I would check the content types in the site collection and reset this back to Title, and then tell whoever may have renamed this column to rename it at the list level and not at the site root.

CSS won't cut it I don't think.

Comment: Thank you! I just deployed a new branding solution so I'm freaking out lol thinking I broke the entire site.  You were correct, someone definitely renamed the title field :|.